# windows 2003 server missing dllcache folder, how to restore?

Tags: windows-server-2003, cache, restore, dll

Recently our Windows 2003 server has started giving a "Could not start the security center service error". I looked into this and realized a windows dll was missing called WSCSVC.dll
I then realized a folder windows\system32\dllcache which otherwise could have been used to restore WSCSVC.DLL to windows\system32 is also missing.  Unfortunately I don't have a backup containing the folder dllcache either.  So what must I do to restore the dllcache folder?
Can I restore these from the original install CDs, without otherwise losing the server configuration?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need the original Windows installation disk available. Stick it in the drive, then run `sfc /scannow`. This will repair any missing Windows system files, and repopulate the DLL cache with any needed files.

Comment: I ran sfc /scannow and it reported no issues/errors.  But the security service still fails due to a missing wscsvc.dll file.  Turns out the dllcahce folder was hidden and it appears to be fully populated but contains no wscsvc.dll file!  What to do now?

Comment: Perhaps you have a virus? The security center service isn't critical for system operation, I believe. It just monitors the status of your A/V and whatnot.

Comment: We have trendmicro's officescan in place and it has not determined any virus.  One would think the sfc /scannow should have realized that the dll was missing from dllcache.  Where can I read about how sfc if all it does is check to see that what is in dllcache is in system32 and then when it is missing a file does nothing what good is that?

Comment: Check the switches of sfc to make sure the cachesize isn't zero. You can also try chkdsk /f.